# for loop is giving partial output in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, asynchronous

I am getting partial output for the  function call. Could anyone tell what I am doing  wrong

> Data in database in JSON format in MongoDB

[DATA IN MONGODB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zsQY.jpg)

> Function code

```
async function isTeamNameExists(department, teamID) {
    var store = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        //database read function
        db.readCollection(collection_name, (status, data) => {
            if (status) {
                var teamname = new SB.ListofNames();
                teamname.listofboards = data;
                var send = teamname;
    
                console.log("send----->", send);
    
                //checking for teamname exists?
    
                for (var boardindex = 0; boardindex < send.listofboards.length; boardindex++) {
                    var tn = send.listofboards[boardindex];
                    if (tn.department == department && tn.teamId == teamId) {
                        resolve(tn);
                    } else {
                        resolve(null);
                    }
                }
                reject(null);
            }
    
        });
    });
    
    console.log("store---->", store); // the function return value =store
    
    return (store);
    //resolve(store); does not work
    
}
```

> Function call 1

```
var output1 = isTeamNameExists(D1,11);
```

> Result-> {department:D1  , teamId:11}    // exists ->returns the particular json data of teamId=11

> Function call 2

```
var output2= isTeamNameExists(D2,22);
```

> Result-> null // it should not return null,but it should return {department:D2  , teamId:22}

> Function call 3

```
var output3= isTeamNameExists(D78b,22000211);
```

> Result-> null // it should return null. correct output

**> So I am getting partial  output. could you tell me what I am doing wrong? I am new to javascript, learning something everyday.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is resolving the moment the first run in the `for (var boardindex = 0; boardindex < send.listofboards.length; boardindex++)` loop is done because of the `else` condition.

You want the loop to go through all the items and `reject` if no entry is found (which you are doing correctly.)

Remove the below part and you'll be good.

```
} else {
  resolve(null);
```

`//resolve(store); does not work` will not work because `isTeamNameExists` function is not a promise.

Comment: If it works for you, please upvote and mark it as an answer so the question will be closed.

Comment: Your function is resolving the moment the first run in the for (var boardindex = 0; boardindex < send.listofboards.length; boardindex++) loop is done because of the else condition.Thanks that was informative. Made the changes you suggested.Now It is  returning Promise Pending . Function call 1,2,3 are returning promise pending. Also i would want Store= null (if there is no data in database).

Comment: you need to use `await` since `isTeamNameExists` is defined to contain `async` functions > `var output1 = await isTeamNameExists(D1,11); `

Comment: for "Also i would want Store= null (if there is no data in database)." you need to use `.catch` as `reject` always throws an error and you need to catch it after the `Promise` or you can just change `reject` to `resolve`

Comment: Your function is resolving the moment the first run in the for (var boardindex = 0; boardindex < send.listofboards.length; boardindex++) loop is done because of the else condition.

You want the loop to go through all the items and reject if no entry is found (which you are doing correctly.)

Remove the below part and you'll be good.

} else {
  resolve(null);  -----> this helped me after a few tries Thank You